# sending inline meeting invite using phmailer failed after multiple effort

Tags: php, outlook, phpmailer

its been three days now, i spend lot of time and efforts on stackoverflow to figure it out, finally thought of posting this question, with the below code i can send email invite but in attachment form, i want inline attachment

i am able to send invite with attached .ical file with below code,
but i dont want attachment, i want inline invite along with mail body,

```
$headers = 'Content-Type:text/calendar; Content-Disposition: inline;
    charset=utf-8;\r\n';
$headers .= "Content-Type: /text/plain;charset=\"utf-8\"\r\n"; 

$attachment="
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//Microsoft Corporation//Outlook 11.0 MIMEDIR//EN
METHOD:REQUEST
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:Asia/Kolkata
BEGIN:STANDARD
TZOFFSETFROM:+0530
TZOFFSETTO:+0530
END:STANDARD
END:VTIMEZONE
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:" . md5(uniqid(mt_rand(), true)) . "example.com
DTEND:". $dbInsertEndTime . "T" . $EndTime . "00
DTSTAMP:" . gmdate('Ymd') . 'T' . gmdate('His') . "Z
DTSTART:". $dbInsertStartDate . "T" . $StartTime . "00
SUMMARY:" . $subject . "
ORGANIZER;CN=Foobar:mailto:foobar@myemail.com
LOCATION:" . $Location . "
DESCRIPTION:" . $desc . "
TRANSP:TRANSPARENT
BEGIN:VALARM
TRIGGER:-PT30M
ACTION:DISPLAY
DESCRIPTION:Reminder
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR";

$headers .= $attachment;


$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;  
$mail->Host = 'xxxxxxxxxx';
$mail->Port = 25;                                    // TCP port to connect to
$mail->Username = EMAIL;                 // SMTP username
$mail->Password = PASS;           
$mail->setFrom(EMAIL, 'xxxx');
$ext = "@outlook.com";
$mail->addAddress($my_ID.$ext);     // Add a recipient
$mail->addReplyTo(EMAIL);
$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
$mail->Subject = ($subject);
$mail->addStringAttachment($attachment,'invite.ics','base64','text/calendar');


$mail->Body    = "<html>
<head>
<title>Meeeting Invite</title>
<style type='text/css'>
table.example2 {background-color:transparent;border-collapse:collapse;width:100%;}
table.example2 th, table.example2 td {text-align:center;border:1px solid black;padding:5px;}
table.example2 th {background-color:AntiqueWhite;}
table.example2 td:first-child {width:15%;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p>Dear ". $Employee_Name. " ,<br /><br /></p>
<p>Your meeting  Scheduled.<br /></p>
</body>
</html>
";
```

Comment: able to get it work, but with attachment as .ics file, i want inline attachment

Answer (score 0):

Why not use PHPMailer’s built-in iCal support?

```
$mail->Ical = $attachment;
```

All that messing with headers you’re doing is counter-productive - let PHPMailer deal with it for you.

Bear in mind that iCal support in email clients is *very* inconsistent, so don’t expect it to work the same way on different systems.

Comment: i tried this but again nothing expect mail body content

Comment: You’ve not posted your revised code or debug output, so I can’t tell you anything more.

Comment: No Luck yet, can someone please come up with solution to this ?